# Close File Upload Window with Javascript or iMacros

Tags: javascript, imacros

I'm trying to upload a file to myself in this [site](https://web.whatsapp.com/) with iMacros and Javascript.
But when I click the file upload window, the window never closes.

This is my imacros code:

```
send_message ="CODE:";
send_message += 'EVENT TYPE=CLICK SELECTOR="#main>HEADER>DIV:nth-of-type(3)>DIV>DIV:nth-of-type(2)>BUTTON" BUTTON=0'+"\n";
send_message += 'WAIT SECONDS=1'+"\n";
send_message += 'EVENT TYPE=CLICK SELECTOR="#main>HEADER>DIV:nth-of-type(3)>DIV>DIV:nth-of-type(2)>SPAN>DIV>DIV>UL>LI>BUTTON" BUTTON=0'+"\n";
send_message += 'WAIT SECONDS=1'+"\n";
send_message += 'TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:FILE ATTR=* CONTENT=/Users/user/Downloads/image002.jpg'+"\n";
send_message += 'WAIT SECONDS=1'+"\n";
send_message += 'EVENT TYPE=CLICK SELECTOR="#app>DIV>DIV>DIV>SPAN:nth-of-type(2)>DIV>SPAN>DIV>DIV>DIV:nth-of-type(2)>SPAN:nth-of-type(2)>DIV>BUTTON" BUTTON=0'+"\n";

send_message_code =  iimPlay(send_message);
```

How can I close the file upload window directly with Javascript or using iMacros?

Comment: You simply don't need to open the file upload dialog. So, remove the 2nd or/and 4th line from your macro.